# How to uncheck the userprofile picture property display setting options using powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, user-profile-property

I need to hide the user profile picture property in edit your profile dialog,

[image]

I tried

```
$userProfileConfigManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileConfigManager($serviceContext)
    $userProfilePropertyManager = $userProfileConfigManager.ProfilePropertyManager
    $userProfileProperties = $userProfilePropertyManager.GetCoreProperties()
    $userProfileSubTypeProperties = $userProfilePropertyManager.GetProfileSubtypeProperties("UserProfile")
    $userProfileTypeProperties = $userProfilePropertyManager.GetProfileTypeProperties([Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileType]::User)

#Change the property PictureURL to user editable
    $subtypeProp = $userProfileSubTypeProperties.GetPropertyByName("PictureURL")
    $subtypeProp.IsUserEditable = $false
    $subtypeProp.Commit()
```

I restricted the user to upload, But I am unable to hide that, Please suggest me an idea to solve this.